# linux command has different behaviour in script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to create a script that does something if my disk arrays fail.
When I run the command it has to return the number 4 (`grep` counted 4 times the word OK, one time for each disk).

Then I want to check if there were 4 or less OKs and do something.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$okdevices = hpssacli controller slot=4 physicaldrive all show | grep -c "OK"
if [ $okdevices -lt 4 ]
then
    echo "disk missing"
fi
```

This returns an error saying that it expects a unary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong command output assign to variable, you are evaluating the string "hpssacli controller slot=4 physicaldrive all show | grep -c OK" with "4"

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
okdevices="$(hpssacli controller slot=4 physicaldrive all show | grep -c OK)"
if [ $okdevices -lt 4 ]; then
    echo "missing disk"
fi
```